# Why does this command remove more packages than I want it to?

Tags: apt, package-management, regular-expression

When I run the following command:

```
# apt-get purge unity-scopes-m*
```

I expect it to delete the following packages:

```
unity-scope-manpages
unity-scope-musicstores
unity-scope-musique
```

Instead, it wants to purge a whole slew of packages I wasn't expecting it to:

```
Note, selecting 'unity-scopes-impl-0' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'unity-scopes-impl-1' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'unity-scopes-impl-4' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'unity-scopes-impl-6' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'unity-scopes-master-default' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'libunity-scopes-qt-dev' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'unity-scopes-json-def' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'libunity-scopes-qt' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'libunity-scopes-qt-doc' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'unity-scopes-runner' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'libunity-scopes-dev' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'libunity-scopes-json-def-phone' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'libunity-scopes-doc' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'unity-scopes-master' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'unity-scopes-impl' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'libunity-scopes-cli' for regex 'unity-scopes-m*'
Note, selecting 'unity-scopes-master-default' instead of 'unity-scopes-master'
Note, selecting 'unity-plugin-scopes' instead of 'unity-scopes-impl'
Note, selecting 'unity-plugin-scopes' instead of 'unity-scopes-impl-0'
Note, selecting 'unity-plugin-scopes' instead of 'unity-scopes-impl-1'
Note, selecting 'unity-plugin-scopes' instead of 'unity-scopes-impl-4'
Note, selecting 'unity-plugin-scopes' instead of 'unity-scopes-impl-6'
Package 'libunity-scopes-cli' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libunity-scopes-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libunity-scopes-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libunity-scopes-json-def-phone' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libunity-scopes-qt' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libunity-scopes-qt-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libunity-scopes-qt-doc' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  account-plugin-aim account-plugin-jabber account-plugin-salut account-plugin-yahoo brasero brasero-cdrkit deja-dup
  deja-dup-backend-gvfs empathy gir1.2-unity-5.0 libbrasero-media3-1 libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop libunity-webapps0 libunity9
  mcp-account-manager-uoa nautilus nautilus-sendto nautilus-share rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder shotwell telepathy-indicator
  thunderbird-gnome-support ubuntu-desktop unity unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-photos
  unity-lens-video unity-scope-audacious unity-scope-calculator unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks unity-scope-clementine
  unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-devhelp unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-gmusicbrowser
  unity-scope-gourmet unity-scope-guayadeque unity-scope-home unity-scope-manpages unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-musique
  unity-scope-openclipart unity-scope-texdoc unity-scope-tomboy unity-scope-video-remote unity-scope-virtualbox unity-scope-yelp
  unity-scope-zotero unity-scopes-master-default unity-scopes-runner unity-webapps-common unity-webapps-qml unity-webapps-service
  usb-creator-gtk webapp-container xul-ext-unity xul-ext-websites-integration
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 60 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 39.7 MB disk space will be freed.
```

Why is the command gobbling up many more packages than I expect it to? According to the `apt-get` manual:

> If no package matches the given expression and the expression contains one of `.`, `?` or `*` then it is assumed to be a POSIX regular expression, and it is applied to all package names in the database. Any matches are then installed (or removed).

There are no files in my current directory causing Bash to expand the `*`, and the same problem happens even if I put `unity-scope-m*` in single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

The additional packages are most likely dependencies of the main packages you expect to be removed.

Are you certain those are the only packages that match that string pattern? Check with:

```
rpm -qa | grep unity-scopes-m
```

Comment: on debian-like system you can list the matching packages with: `$ dpkg -l unity-scope-m*`